# Regular Exp instead of string split

Tags: c#

I had an exam two days before one of the questions was to replace the letters before the @ with a new names

so in the exam paper the we had array = "toto@yahoo.com","mimi@yahoo.com".soso@yahoo.com"
so we sholud take the toto mimi soso and replace them with diffrent names what i did is to split the string and take the first four letters and thank god i got the mark .

I was thinking what if the number of letters befor the @ was not fixed
what other ways i can do ? Reg Exp or is there a diffrent way.

Answer (score 5):

You could use RegEx or you could do string manipulation based on Substring, IndexOf and concatenation.

Comment: Agreed! This is much easily done using simple string searching.

Comment: should be String.lastIndexOf(), not IndexOf()

Comment: @Alnitak: from the examples provided both will work and I assume that the OP will be able to pick the right one based on the actual case.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex, you could do search for strings like [a-zA-Z]*@ and replace it with whatever-you-desire.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Treb, don't use RegEx's for parsing e-mail addresses!

There's no end of legal characters that are possible on the left hand side of the "@", and in particular the left hand side can actually be a quoted string, which could itself contain an "@", i.e.:

```
"Some odd e-m@il address!"@example.com
```

See section 3.4.1 of [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).

Therefore the string split should be done based on the *right-most* "@" sign, since that certainly can't appear in the domain part of the address.

Comment: ah well being an email format is special - they're almost strictly unparseable for a regex if you try and match what the standard allows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd do this with a Regex.

Simple match techniques along the lines of split, substring, indexof tend to be fast but - as you've found - inflexible, and the thing is regexs are *really* fast anyway in the scheme of things. Unless the operation is in a long loop (which will therefore magnify a performance cost) I generally suggest that the future flexibility and clarity of intent is worth employing a regex for.

Comment: regex -> clarity? I don't think so.

Comment: I knew that would be controversial. Yes regex = clarity. Regex.replace says "I am trying to replace something" far clearer than x = foo + substring + bar. If you don't get regex that's your own lookout, but the action it performs is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Regex would work, but just getting the position of the @ with `IndexOf` and extracting the address part with `Substring` as proposed by [Brian Rasmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519680/regular-exp-instead-of-string-split/519686#519686) is simpler. When in doubt, go for simpler (in other words: the  [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) applies).

Answer (score -1):

This may help :

```
// I want to replace soso with tania
string result = Regex.Replace("soso@yahoo.com", "([a-zA-Z0-9._]*)([@][a-zA-Z0-9._]*)", "tania$2");
```